# javascript shows all associated DIVs on a dropdown box select

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and must have looked at almost all of the previous questions here and elsewhere related to this question and none seem to do the trick because they use asp, php, Ajax etc. 
I use jQuery code for several other items on the page and have found that their css can cause issues with my pages and am not keen on using it either.

In my case, is there a way to select a country from a drop down box and then display a dropdown box with the states or provinces for that country. My code is shown below but when I run it, it shows all DIVs and not just the DIV that applies to the country selected.  If a country has no states/province it will display nothing but passes a value of 0. 
I'd like to know what is wrong with this code.

Second question is, the page starts with a default country and its states/provinces but since I use onChange on the country select, the javascript would not be triggered because initially there is no change.  Regardless, even when I do change the country from its default, all DIVs are displayed anyway.

Is it possible to show the states/provinces for the default country and still use javascript for any change made to the default selection.  It does not show this in the sample below, but the values for the countries and the associated states/provinces come from a database and can therefore not be incorporated in the javascript.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
<TABLE>
    <TR><TD>Country</DIV></TD>
        <TD><SELECT NAME="countryid" onChange="showstate(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <OPTION VALUE="NONE">Select a country</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="CA" SELECTED>Canada</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="US">United States</OPTION>
            <OPTION VALUE="ES">Spain</OPTION>
        </SELECT></TD>
    </TR>

<script>
 function showstate(country) {
    if (country == "CA") {
    hiddenDivUS.style.display='none';
    hiddenDivNONE.style.display='none';
    hiddenDivCA.style.display='block';
    } 
    else {
    if (country == "US") {
    hiddenDivCA.style.display='none';
    hiddenDivNONE.style.display='none';
    hiddenDivUS.style.display='block';
    } 
    else {
    hiddenDivCA.style.display='none';
    hiddenDivUS.style.display='none';
    hiddenDivNONE.style.display='block';
    }
  } 
</script>   

    <DIV ID="hiddenDivNONE" STYLE="display:none">
        <TR><TD><DIV CLASS="inputlabel">Prov/State</DIV></TD>
            <TD><INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="provid" VALUE="0"></TD>
        </TR>     
    </DIV>

    <DIV ID="hiddenDivCA" STYLE="display:none">
        <TR><TD><DIV CLASS="inputlabel">Prov/State</DIV></TD>
            <TD><SELECT NAME="provid">
                <OPTION VALUE="101">British Columbia</OPTION>
                .......
                <OPTION VALUE="165">Yukon Territories</OPTION>
            </SELECT></TD>
        </TR>     
    </DIV>

    <DIV ID="hiddenDivUS" STYLE="display:none">
        <TR><TD><DIV CLASS="inputlabel">Prov/State</DIV></TD>
            <TD><SELECT NAME="provid">
                <OPTION VALUE="201">Alaska</OPTION>
                .......
                <OPTION VALUE="265">Wyoming</OPTION>
            </SELECT></TD>
        </TR>     
    </DIV>
</TABLE>
```

Instead of listing the proper DIV it shows all three of them

Answer (score 0):

First off, careful with your capitals.

Secondly try to keep all js at the bottom of the page.

This code is using ES6 so you might wanna check if it will work in all browsers but you can see whats going on.

el.classList is supported by most browsers however `add`,`remove` and `toggle` are not (were not.. not sure now)

I have used some regex to grab all elements using the id `state_` so we can hide them, then we target the exact one to make it visible, you can probably clean that up also.

```
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>


<select name="countryid" onChange="showState(event)">
    <option value="">Select a country</option>
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="us">United States</option>
    <option value="es">Spain</option>
</select>

<div id="state_ca" class="hidden">
  This is hidden unless Canada is selected.
</div>
<div id="state_us" class="hidden">
  This is hidden unless America is selected.
</div>

<script>
    function showState(event) {
        const countryCode = event.target.value;
        const states = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=state_]');
        const el = document.getElementById(`state_${countryCode}`);

        states.forEach(el => {
            if (el.classList.contains('hidden')) {
                return;
            }
            el.classList.add('hidden');
        });

        if (el) {
            el.classList.remove('hidden');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it returned the exact same as my original code in Firefox and Chrome. I get both the ca and us provinces/states in two separate dropdown boxes below the country select. Also, given my inexperience with JS, why create a separate `hidden` class and using `class=hidden` instead of using style="display:none;" Seems to me they would achieve the same result,no? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to me this can be the answer to your problem. You can make a few changes in the code which I have not done.

```js
function addStates() {
  var selectCountry = document.getElementById("selectCountry").value;
  console.log(selectCountry);
  var selectState = document.getElementById("selectState");
  if (selectCountry == "india") {
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    option1.value = "punjab";
    option1.text = "Punjab";
    selectState.add(option1);
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option2.value = "karnataka";
    option2.text = "Karnataka";
    selectState.add(option2);
  } else if (selectCountry == "usa") {
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    option1.value = "florida";
    option1.text = "Florida";
    selectState.add(option1);
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option2.value = "california";
    option2.text = "California";
    selectState.add(option2);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Select a country: </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select onchange="addStates()" id="selectCountry">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Please select a country</option>
        <option value="india">India</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span>Please select a state: </span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select id="selectState">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Ishaan. Unfortunately your code does not seem to work and displays both the Indian and US states in a single dropdown box, twice.  As mentioned in my post, my state and country names also come from a database and I have not been able to generate individual country/state name options inside the javascript with the software I use so your solution would be problematic for me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get the desired result (see code below)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <script>
    function showStates(country)
    {
        if (country == "101") 
        {   document.getElementById('CAprov').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('Default').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('USstate').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('NoProv').style.display='none';
        }
        else if (country == "102")
        {   document.getElementById('CAprov').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('Default').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('USstate').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('NoProv').style.display='none';
        }
        else
        {   document.getElementById('CAprov').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('USstate').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('Default').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('NoProv').style.display='block';
        }
        return false;
    }
    </script>

    </HEAD>
    <BODY TOPMARGIN="0" LEFTMARGIN="0" MARGINHEIGHT="0" MARGINWIDTH="0" BORDER="0">
    <FORM METHOD="post">
    <TABLE>
        <TR><TD>Country</TD>
            <TD><SELECT NAME="country" id="country" onChange="showStates(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                <OPTION VALUE="101" SELECTED>Canada</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="102">United States</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="314">Germany</OPTION>
            </SELECT></TD></TR>
        <TR ID="Default" STYLE="display: block;"><TD>Province</TD>
            <TD><SELECT NAME="provid">
                <OPTION VALUE="0">Select province</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="139">Newfoundland/Labrador</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="143">Nova Scotia</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="134">New Brunswick</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="149">Prince Edward Island</OPTION>
            </SELECT></TD></TR>
        <TR ID="CAprov" STYLE="display: none;"><TD>Province</TD>
            <TD><SELECT NAME="provid">
                <OPTION VALUE="0">Select province</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="139">Newfoundland/Labrador</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="143">Nova Scotia</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="134">New Brunswick</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="149">Prince Edward Island</OPTION>
            </SELECT></TD></TR>
        <TR ID="USstate" STYLE="display: none;"><TD>State</TD>
            <TD><SELECT NAME="provid">
                <OPTION VALUE="0">Select state</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="102">Alabama</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="105">Arizona</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="106">Arkansas</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="108">California</OPTION>
            </SELECT></TD></TR>   
        <TR ID="NoProv" STYLE="display: none;"><TD>Prov/State</TD>
            <TD><INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="provid" VALUE="0">&nbsp;</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: Found the issue caused by the `<TABLE>` statement.  Apparently you cannot do the `DIV` inside a table.  Remove the provinc/state DIVs and apply the `id` and `style` elements to the `<TR>` instead and it works fine. i.e `<TR ID="USstate" STYLE="display: none">`